# C# Запуск программы после входа пользователем в систему

Tags: c#

Есть программа, которая прописывает себя в автозагрузку. Все работает, все отлично.

```
RegistryKey reg;
reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\", true);
reg.SetValue("PCVision", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Но есть одна проблема, когда пользователь ставит и снимает компьютер со сна - программа понятным образом не запускается. так как полноценной перезагрузки системы не происходит.

Собственно вопрос, возможно кто-то из вас уже ранее стыкался с подобным и знает как правильно выйти из этой ситуации.

Answer (score 6):

Сомневаюсь, что реестре есть раздел, отвечающий за это. Например, гугл молчит на запрос вида "run program after power change". Да и с трудом представляю когда бы это могло кому-нибудь понадобиться => Microsoft, скорее всего, не стали реализовывать невостребованный функционал.

Если бы это и было, то в пользовательском интерфейсе, где-нибудь рядом с местом куда добавляются программы в обычную автозагрузку.

Например, прикладная программа может поймать данные события как в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206183/event-to-detect-system-wake-up-from-sleep-in-c-sharp) примере:

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;

private void OnPowerChange(object s, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    switch ( e.Mode ) 
    {
        case PowerModes.Resume: 
        break;
        case PowerModes.Suspend:
        break;
    }
}
```

Получается, что самое простое - это в фоне крутить какую-нибудь программку/сервис, которая слушает события изменения питания и на основании этого запускает нужный софт.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте запустить приложение(напишите свою службу, которая будет следить, за работой приложения и когда надо запускать.), чтобы поймать событие:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += this.SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;

private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Resume)
    {
        //Ваш код
    }
}
```

ну или через планировщик заданий , триггер на следующее событие:

Журнал Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance

Источник Diagnostics-Performance

Код события 300

или же на "At Workstation Unlock"